# How to print information to a viewport in editor mode in Unreal Engine

Tags: unreal-engine5

How can I print information to a viewport in editor mode in Unreal Engine?

Addonscreendebugmessage does not work in editor mode; it seems to only work in PIE mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look here:
https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/4-9-2-addonscreendebugmessage-doesnt-print-when-editor-is-not-in-game-mode/339789

But you can use "printString" which can be an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I was having exactly the same problem: I created a ScriptedAssetAction that was supposed to print to the screen, but nothing was showing up. I could see that AddOnScreenDebugMessage was being called and I was totally stumped.

For me, the solution was to 'wake up' the screen by entering in a command like 'stat fps'. At this point, I found that not only was the framerate displayed, but a bunch of other, error-related info would suddenly be dispalyed in the viewport, along with the debug messages that my ScriptedAssetActions were trying to print out.

I'm not sure if this is a bug or a feature intended to hide ugly debug messages until you specifically ask for a piece of information, but I certainly found it pretty unintuitive and inconsistent; I'm never quite sure when debug messages are going to turn themselves off again in the Editor.